# Should I use "Conjecture A holds true" or "Conjecture A holds"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I want to write a sentence like "Assume Conjecture A holds true then Conjecture B holds true". But I do not know if it is correct to write "Assume Conjecture A holds then Conjecture B holds".

I saw the first expression several times in papers, but the second expression seems more concise.

Comment: They mean quite different things. Get a clarity. Do a bit of research. Good Luck.

Comment: Then could you let me know what is the difference? I think this is the site I could find the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the second would be understood to the reader as the "true" is implied but I think that the first is more correct. Given the level of paper you'd likely be writing this phrase in I would use the first, longer version. If you really want a concise version, "Conjecture A ⇒ Conjecture B" is another way of writing the same thing if you are specifically writing logic statements rather than an essay/paper.

Comment: Wait till you get the privilege to post comments.

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure what exactly you mean. First, this is an answer to the question not an ask for clarification or response to someone else's answer/comment, so posting it as an answer is valid. Second, getting enough rep to post comments won't happen if I don't answer questions.

Comment: With all due respect to help you, words like "I think...likely...I would" imply opinion. Answers usually call for a more authoritative quality, with citations to back up the standard. Don't worry that authority makes you authoritarian. I can remove this when you ask.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I see your point and certainly citations are helpful for most answers. This question struck me as going beyond just "rules of grammar" into what language is most widely accepted by a particular group of people, hence why I was phrasing it as an opinion. While language is composed of rules, it is also about effectively conveying meaning and there are many things that rules don't cover. I simply didn't want to come off as an authority given the perceived subjectivity of the question and of my answer.